# Calculate SUM based on a column from associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sum, rails-activerecord

I have a table called `vehicles`, which has a column called `vehicle_id` and `price`.

I have a table called `sales`, which references the `vehicles` table. It has the columns `vehicle_id` (references the `vehicle` table) and `sale_status` which can equal to 'sold' or 'loan'.

I am trying to calculate the total price of `vehicles` which equal to 'sold' in the `sales` table. Help is much appreciated!

This is what I have so far but it returns the wrong number.

***vehicle.rb***:

```
def self.vehicles_price_sum
  vehicles_sold.sum(:price).to_f
end

def self.vehicles_sold
  Vehicle.where(id: Sale.where(sale_status: 'Sold'))
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with a subquery (which is close to you solution, yet you need to provide a column name explicitly for `in` clause with `select`, otherwise `sales`' `id` column is going to be provided):

```
Vehicle.where(id: Sale.where(status: "Sold").select(:vehicle_id)).sum(:price)
# SELECT SUM(`vehicles`.`price`) FROM `vehicles` WHERE `vehicles`.`id` IN (SELECT `sales`.`vehicle_id` FROM `sales` WHERE `sales`.`sale_status` = 'Sold')
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! But now it is showing 0 for the sum for both of those answers

Comment: my sale column type is string but there are no commas if that makes a difference?

Comment: @Anderson, how exactly are `sales` and `vehicles` connected, again? `vehicles.vin` is a primary key and `sales.vin` is a foreign key? or is it `vehicles.id` -> `sales.vin`?

Comment: its vehicles.id -> sales.vin

Comment: Thank you so much! I ended up doing that but with .select(:vehicle_id)